# Controller with this name is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on school project using angularjs, I don't know why I'm getting this `Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not registered.`

index.html:

```html
...
<div ng-controller="medscontroller">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="med in meds | filter:{nom:nom} | orderBy:order">{{med.nom}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script >
        function medscontroller($scope){
            $scope.meds=[
            {"nom":"aspirine", "prix":"20"},
            {"nom":"doliprane","prix":"15"},
            {"nom":"da", "prix":"15"}
            ];
            console.log($scope);
            }

    </script>
```

Comment: Side note: if you are working on something (relatively) new then I would recommend you to use angular 2+ https://angular.io

Comment: yes definitely, but since it is a school project I have no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply define a controller function like above.

In order for a controller to work, you have to do the following things.

- Create an angular app with
  `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);`
- Deine a controller for that app with.
  `app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { });`

Find a working example here.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome :). Happy to have an upvote aswell.